# How to compute a rectangle coordinates from one point and its distances to the four edges

Tags: java

I would like to create a `Rectangle` that has got one side different than the other.

(All lines depicted are meant to be straight lines)

The normal rectangle is generated like `new Rectangle(50 /*LocationX*/, 50 */LocationY*/, 50 /*SizeX*/, 100 /*SizeY*/);`, and looks like this:
[image]

However, I want a constructor like `new Rectangle(50 /*LocationX*/, 50 */LocationY*/, 25 /*25 from the centre point for the red line*/, 30 /*30 from the centre point for the blue line*/, 50 /*50 from centre for green line*/, 100 /*100 from centre for yellow line*/);`

In other words, I effectively want to keep the shape the same but move the centre point.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you just want to define a rectangle by defining the horizontal edge distances from a point and the vertical edge distances from the same point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, [rectangles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) are defined by upper-left corner coordinates, width and height.

If I understand your question here what describes *your* rectangle:

- `pointX`, `pointY` coordinates of a point in the rectangle. Named *the point*.
- `distanceToTop` distance from *the point* to the top of the rectangle (green line).
- `distanceToBottom` distance from *the point* to the bottom of the rectangle (yellow line).
- `distanceToLeft` distance from *the point* to the left of the rectangle (red line).
- `distanceToRight` distance from *the point* to the right of the rectangle (blue line).

That given. The upper-left corner of the rectangle has for coordinates:

```
(pointX - distanceToLeft, pointY - distanceToTop)
```

And the whole rectangle has for size *(width, height)*:

```
(distanceToLeft + distanceToRight, distanceToTop + distanceToBottom)
```

So your instance will be:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(
    pointX - distanceToLeft,           // upper-left corner X
    pointY - distanceToTop,            // upper-left corner Y
    distanceToLeft + distanceToRight,  // width
    distanceToTop + distanceToBottom   // height
    );
```

Comment: Have rectangles always started in the top left?

Comment: @Joehot200, yes they are. I added a linked to java doc.